# How to design a contrast matrix with combined levels for a categorical variable?

Tags: r, linear-model, contrasts

I wish to make a contrast matrix in the case of a linear model. 
I have one factor with three levels: `T`, `N` and `A`.
I want the contrasts `T` vs `N`, `T` vs `A` and `T` vs (`N` and `A` combined).
It is the last contrast with combined levels that cause troubles.

The "correct" result I can get by redefining `N` and `A` to a new combined level `L` and then make a one column contrast matrix `T = 1`, `L = -1`.
But how to do it when this level is split into two?

The `T = 2`, `N = -1`, `A = -1` column does not give the result of the above one col contrast.

I'm implementing it in R.
The number of observations are T=30, N=14, A=15

Answer (score 1):

If the correct result is obtained by T=1 and L=-1, then I would consider using T=1,N=-1,A=-1.